# Transaction unconfirmed for 5 days, and I don't think the fee is the problem?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I sent a transaction of ~0.408 BTC February 20th through Electrum and my transaction is still showing up as unconfirmed. I also cannot resend my transaction through Electrum as the coins are still unconfirmed. Here is my Tx on the Blockchain

https://blockchain.info/tx/0a33becac294dd987f2374f3fcbba2b4a37cbca6807e8296e2d439f919cafe36

I included a fee as well. Any idea whats wrong or how I can retrieve my Bitcoins?

Answer (score 1):

The fee you have set leads a "fee per byte" value of ~20 satoshi/byte, as you can see on the blockchain.info. It's too small currently, as transactions with fees lesser than 60 sat/B doesn't seem to be trusted to clear right now, as you may see here: [bitcoinfees.21.co](https://bitcoinfees.21.co/). I could help you with clearing it, but I'm pretty sure the thread about it already exists here. The problem is likely solvable, good luck.